# error coming in magento2.1 catagories

Tags: magento-2.1

I face this problem.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool::__construct() must implement interface  or be null, array given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Pricing\Price\Pool.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\Pool->__construct(Array, Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Framewo...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(71): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Configu...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(144): Magento\Framework\Ob in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\Pricing\Price\Pool.php on line 23

[image]

How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
sudo rm -rf var/* generated/*
```

Then

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento ca:fl
php bin/magento ca:cl
```